# Could not load berkshelf

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, berkshelf

I am working on chef projects and trying to run kitchen list command. Unfortunately I am getting Could not load or activate berkshelf. I have given the command gem install berkshelf. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and installed chefdk. THank you.

Error log :

```
kitchen list
!!!!!! The `berkshelf' gem is missing and must be installed or cannot be properly activated. Run `gem install berkshelf` or add the following to your Gemfile if you are using Bundler: `gem 'berkshelf'`.
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::UserError
>>>>>> Message: Could not load or activate Berkshelf (Unable to activate sawyer-0.8.1, because addressable-2.6.0 conflicts with addressable (>= 2.3.5, < 2.6))
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have given the command gem install berkshelf

make sure that you are using a Gemfile and include berkshelf within it. then let bundler install your rubygems and once complete, try to the same command under bundler. e.g.:

```
$ bundle exec kitchen list
```

or even

```
$ bundle exec berks --version
```